# git filter-branch --tree-filter with --since returns "Found nothing to rewrite"

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm trying to perform a command on all commits since a certain date:

`git filter-branch -f --tree-filter <command> HEAD -- --since="2014-06-01 13:37" <name-of-branch>`

Unfortunately it always outputs `Found nothing to rewrite` and stops. Everything after `--` should be treated as an option for `rev-list` so if I try:

`git rev-list --since="2014-06-01 13:37" <name-of-branch>`

I'll get the correct set of all revisions since 2014-06-01.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the `filter-branch` script; it winds up calling `git rev-list` with two `--` arguments, but `git rev-list` only works correctly with one.  The actual source of the bug is not clear to me, but in git-as-it-is you can't actually pass these options to `git rev-list`.

Comment: Thanks @torek - I appreciate you looking into it. So it's not me, it's `git`! :) Why don't you post an answer with this info and I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't really have time to write a proper answer, but if you like, I'll copy the comment to an answer...

Comment: Sure. I would do it myself but then you don't get reputation (not that you need it *that* much! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I copied a git repo and ran the `filter-branch` script with similar options (just making up a different `--since` to select a rev or two out of those on a particular branch), and found that deep in the script, where the documentation says that arguments following `--` are passed on to `git rev-list`, the filter-branch code winds up passing these arguments as if they were path specifiers.  This seems like a bug in filter-branch.

In particular:

```
$ git rev-list --since=2013-01-01 branch
222c4dd303570d096f0346c3cd1dff6ea2c84f83
$ git rev-list branch
222c4dd303570d096f0346c3cd1dff6ea2c84f83
fb45c22c932d16903ae9e4debb8483a58a4e7799
fc85842f31baa62292abc3a539e86d0971caf8d9
2a5aaf8429ad810b25ef49f62bfda302b3193852
630a11ba2516023246e1e3eccf7023e915870489
4b597cf400a040a6bb14329890d65f126be88af2
```

This shows that if I deliberately rewrite `branch` itself, it should copy (with filtering) six commits, but with `--since=2013-01-01` it should just copy (with filtering) one commit.  Since I'm not actually on branch `branch` I will also replace `HEAD` above with `branch` just to eliminate the question of what it means to rewrite the branch `HEAD` names, while selecting revs pointed-to by `branch`.

Meanwhile, I provide a pointless tree filter (that makes no changes, but provides some output).  Thus, my filter-branch command is:

```
$ git filter-branch -f --tree-filter ls branch -- --since=2013-01-01 branch
Found nothing to rewrite
```

Now let's expose the inner workings of `git filter-branch`.  To do this I must temporarily put `/usr/local/libexec/git-core` on my `$PATH`:

```
$ c=/usr/local/libexec/git-core  # so I don't have to retype it
$ PATH=$c:$PATH sh -x $c/git-filter-branch \
>  -f --tree-filter ls branch -- --since=2013-01-01 branch
```

The `-x` shows each line as it runs.  There's a whole bunch of setup, and then the output includes this:

```
+ git rev-parse --no-flags --revs-only --symbolic-full-name --default HEAD branch -- --since=2013-01-01 branch
+ sed -e /^^/d /tmp/t2/.git-rewrite/raw-heads
```

(this obtains the list of "positives refs to rewrite"; this part is correct despite the apparent "extra" `--`)

```
+ test -s /tmp/t2/.git-rewrite/heads
```

(this makes sure there is at least one branch name to rewrite)

```
+ pwd
+ GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/t2/.git-rewrite/t/../index
+ export GIT_INDEX_FILE
```

(this is more setup for index filter and such)

```
+ mkdir ../map
+ git rev-parse --no-revs branch -- --since=2013-01-01 branch
+ nonrevs='--
--since=2013-01-01
branch'
+ test -z '--
--since=2013-01-01
branch'
+ dashdash=''
+ remap_to_ancestor=t
```

This checks the arguments to pass on to `git rev-list` looking for whether there are path-based revision limiters.  It decides that there *are*: the `-- since=...` is viewed as a pathspec, so this sets `$dashdash` to empty and `remap_to_ancestors` to `t` (short for true).  Oddly, `$dashdash` is used only if we supplied a `--subdirectory-filter`, which we did not.  This code looks suspicious but is not itself the direct source of the problem.

The next bit:

```
+ git rev-parse --revs-only branch -- --since=2013-01-01 branch
```

writes the list of revs to rewrite to a temp file (`../parse`, not shown here).  In my case that's where `branch` points which is `222c4dd...` itself.  This is OK as far as it goes, but next:

```
+ git rev-parse --sq --no-revs branch -- --since=2013-01-01 branch
+ eval set -- \''--'\'' '\''--since=2013-01-01'\'' '\''branch'\'' '
+ set -- -- --since=2013-01-01 branch
```

This updates the arguments to "just those to pass to `git rev-list`", and then:

```
+ git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --default HEAD --parents --simplify-merges --stdin -- --since=2013-01-01 branch
+ wc -l
+ tr -d ' '
+ commits=0
+ test 0 -eq 0
+ die 'Found nothing to rewrite'
```

The last `git rev-list` above is supposed to produce the final set of commits-to-rewrite.  The original set (from `--stdin` and the temp file `../parse`) is correct, but this has passed `--since=... branch` as path specifiers (purely *limiting* revisions), rather than additional revision generators (possibly *adding* revs, as with `--all`).

If you use some of the examples from the manual pages, such as (I've modified this one to be a no-op):

```
git filter-branch --env-filter : -- --all
```

they work because `git rev-parse` understands `--all` so that it is not passed to the last `git filter-branch`:

```
+ git rev-list --reverse --topo-order --default HEAD --parents --simplify-merges --stdin
```

In fact, the `--all` has resulted in refs going into the `parse` file, which is the `--stdin` contents so this works on all reachable commits.

---

Anyway, while this is way too long (because I don't have time to shorten it), it boils down to the fact that, at least right now, you cannot use `--since` limiters here.  They probably *should* work but it would require the filter-branch script to parse arguments more cleverly (perhaps with the help of `git rev-parse`).  If that last "set" had not inserted a literal `--`, the `rev-list ... --stdin` would have received `--since=... branch` as arguments and would do the right thing.  For actual path limiters, though, there should be a `--`.

It's not clear to me whether the bug is that the filter-branch documentation suggests that *all* rev-list options are allowed here (when they are not), or that the code around the part of the script I've highlighted should be smarter, or maybe just different (e.g., perhaps path limiters should require *two* `--` arguments).  But one way or another, it must be a bug in git, because the documentation suggests that `--since` could work, and it does not.

Comment: Thanks for a *very* thorough answer!